# Convert multiple subqueries into a join (Join table to itself)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, self-join

```
Table structures 

Table Products :
=============================================
ID | Store | Type | Cost | NetCost | 
=============================================
1  |102    | 0    |14.95 | 29.65
2  |103    | 1    |13.95 | 32.65
3  |104    | 2    |12.36 | 42.12
4  |105    | 3    |10.24 | 23.11
5  |106    | 4    |19.57 | 27.16
6  |102    | 0    |57.26 | 26.98
7  |103    | 3    |43.26 | 26.98
8  |104    | 4    |10.26 | 26.98
9  |105    | 1    |9.26  | 26.98
10 |105    | 5    |11.26 | 46.98


Same table separated into  two tables by Type
Premium products  : Type = ( 0, 1, 2 )
Basic products    : Type = ( 3, 4, 5 )

Table Products : Products with Type (0,1,2)
=============================================
ID | Store | Type | Cost | NetCost | 
=============================================
1  |102    | 0    |14.95 | 29.65
2  |103    | 1    |13.95 | 32.65
3  |104    | 2    |12.36 | 42.12
6  |102    | 0    |57.26 | 26.98
9  |105    | 1    |9.26  | 26.98

Table Products : Products with Type (3,4,5)
=============================================
ID | Store | Type | Cost | NetCost | 
=============================================
4  |105    | 3    |10.24 | 23.11
5  |106    | 4    |19.57 | 27.16
7  |103    | 3    |43.26 | 26.98
8  |104    | 4    |10.26 | 26.98
10 |105    | 5    |11.26 | 46.98
```

**I want to sum Count, Cost and NetCost for all Products based on Type grouped by Store.
The result should look like the following :**

```
Table of totals: (B = Basic, P= Premium)
=================================================================
Store | B Cnt |B Cost | B NetCost | P Cnt | P Cost | P NetCost | 
=================================================================
102
103
104
105
106
```

I can achieve the above by using a master query with the subqueries shown below, is there a more 
efficient join (joining table to itself etc) I can do that will achieve the table (totals) above ?

Subqueries that I would place in a master query :

```
SELECT  
    count(*)
FROM 
    Products prod_prem
WHERE   
    (prod_prem.Type =  0 OR prod_prem.Type = 1 OR prod_prem.Type = 2)

SELECT  
    SUM(Cost),
FROM 
    Products prod_prem
WHERE   
    (prod_prem.Type =  0 OR prod_prem.Type = 1 OR prod_prem.Type = 2)

SELECT  
    SUM(NetCost)
FROM 
    Products prod_prem
WHERE   
    (prod_prem.Type =  0 OR prod_prem.Type = 1 OR prod_prem.Type = 2)


SELECT  
    count(*)
FROM 
    Products prod_basic
WHERE   
    (prod_prem.Type =  3 OR prod_prem.Type = 4 OR prod_prem.Type = 5)


SELECT  
    SUM(Cost),
FROM 
    Products prod_basic
WHERE   
    (prod_prem.Type =  3 OR prod_prem.Type = 4 OR prod_prem.Type = 5)


SELECT  
    SUM(NetCost)
FROM 
    Products prod_basic
WHERE   
    (prod_prem.Type =  3 OR prod_prem.Type = 4 OR prod_prem.Type = 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in single query using `Conditional Aggregation`

```
SELECT Store,
       [B Cnt] = Count(CASE WHEN Type IN ( 3, 4, 5 ) THEN 1 END),
       [B Cost] = Sum(CASE WHEN Type IN ( 3, 4, 5 ) THEN Cost ELSE 0 END),
       [B NetCost] = Sum(CASE WHEN Type IN ( 3, 4, 5 ) THEN NetCost ELSE 0 END),
       [P Cnt] = Count(CASE WHEN Type IN ( 0, 1, 2 ) THEN 1 END),
       [P Cost] = Sum(CASE WHEN Type IN ( 0, 1, 2 ) THEN Cost ELSE 0 END),
       [P NetCost] = Sum(CASE WHEN Type IN ( 0, 1, 2 ) THEN NetCost ELSE 0 END)
FROM   Products
GROUP  BY Store
```

Comment: This looks much cleaner and understandable, I will try it later on today and accept your answer if it works out . Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a ProductType table with an IsPremium bit column. That way you don't have to do horrible error prone maintenance of your code when type 6, 7, 8.. come along - you just insert new rows in the type table.

Comment: I don't mantain the tables so I have to work with them as they are.

Comment: Gotcha. If this is in a stored procedure, you could to create it as a temporary table within the procedure so the "premiumness" is only defined in one place in the proc rather than many. Might be more trouble than its worth, just a suggestion